# (0 == variable) or (null == obj): An outdated practice in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, coding-style

#### Exact duplicate:

> [Why does one often see “null != variable” instead of “variable != null” in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271561/why-does-one-often-see-null-variable-instead-of-variable-null-in-c)

I have seen senior developers using syntaxes mentioned in the title.
Is there a need for specifying a constant first in .NET? (as opposed to in C/C++ world)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271561/why-does-one-often-see-null-variable-instead-of-variable-null-in-c ?

Comment: Ah, gosh, why did the other question use "!=" not "=="... i wasn't able to find that post... again...

Comment: @Burkhard: Thanks Burkhard for the 2nd time.

Comment: We could really do with the FAQ idea being implemented: http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/general/suggestions/138261-allow-a-per-tag-home-faq-page

As SO grows, it's getting harder to find the duplicates even if you know they're there.

Comment: Yes. this is the 2nd time that I had to post a dupe while I could have just looked up the original answer. Voting on User voice

Comment: @Jon -- it's easier if you use Google and site:stackoverflow.com, though I would agree on the need for more FAQs.

Comment: Sung Meister, i don't know any programmer personally who does it in C++. there is still the case of if(var = var) which would still be valid. best put on compiler warnings and write the way it most pleases you.

Comment: (0==var) syntax seems so unnatural to read in my opinion.  I think I should probably try to switch them around (if you use Resharper, you can switch them around using "Ctrl+Shift+Alt+ LEFT or RIGHT arrow keys"

Comment: @tvanfosson: I kind of started searching for SO posts through google...

Comment: and even if you write 0==var, there are still enough sources of bugs. you could write >= as > or != or whatever and no compiler warns you. i mostly regard it as a way for programmers to "show off" what they know about that assigning to 0 isn't possible. but i don't see real use in it.

Comment: @Sung Meister: Yes, I usually use Google to find old posts. When I'm trying to find my own posts, the adverts get in my way though :( Trouble is, a question like this is hard to find - it could say anything.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, there's no need for this, because the problem it tries to avoid - namely the typo of:

```
if (variable = 0)
```

wouldn't compile in C# anyway. The conditions in `if` statements have to be Boolean. There's still a risk of making one of these mistakes:

```
if (something = true)
if (something = false)
```

if `something` is a Boolean variable, but the better way to fix this is to avoid the constant:

```
if (something)
if (!something)
```

If you have developers bringing over idioms like this from other languages without thinking about whether they're appropriate in C#, you should keep an eye for them doing more of the same. If you try to write C# as if it's C++ (or any other language, pretty much - with the possible exception of VB.NET) you'll end up writing non-idiomatic C# code.

EDIT: As cletus noted, there *is* another potential area for concern:

```
bool a = false, b = true; 
if (a = b) { } // No warnings
```

So the error can still occur - but then we're outside the realm of comparing with a constant anyway :) I'd say this crops up incredibly rarely, and isn't worth too much time spent worrying about it.

Comment: So the (0==variable) syntax might be a remnant habit in C/C++?

Comment: No "might be" about it.  it is.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Your second 50K of rep is going to be from answering dupes of the questions that got you your first 50K :P

Comment: It's worth noting that: bool a = false, b = true; if (a = b) { } generates NO warnings.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Thank you for the update comment.

Comment: @cletus: that's something I should keep in mind. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 10):

There is no need for this syntax in the modern world.  It's a habit that many of us got into when our C compiler wouldn't warn us that we were about to launch the missiles.

```
if(status = RED_ALERT)
{
    launchMissiles();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I suspect this is a leftover habit.  In C:

```
 if (0 = variable)
```

will throw a compiler error whereas

```
 if (variable = 0)
```

will not.

Answer (score 0):

It's not needed *for C#*.  But It's still a good idea.

Programming is all about habit and you never know when you'll find yourself writing some javascript or updating an old program you thought was long gone.

Comment: Wouldn't you say it affects readability a bit, though? When we read the code out loud: We're not checking if zero equals a variable. We already know only zero can only equal zero. We want to check if the variable equals zero.

Comment: I don't know: I think it's pretty clear either way.

Comment: I've heard the readability reasoning many times, but I've never considered it an issue either.  The == operator is symmetric (unless you override it!), so x == 0 should read just the same as 0 == x.  I know from past arguments that I'm in the minority. :)

Comment: For some reason i found (null == obj) to be quite unnatural when I "speak" that part of code in my mind...   Usually one would say "when an object is null" not "null is object"..

Comment: Programming *shouldn't* be about habit. You should absolutely be aware of what language you're using - use the appropriate idioms for the language.