# Should I check to see if an object is null first or second?

Tags: c#

Say for example that I create a Duck

```
Duck myDuck = DuckFactory.CreateDuck();
```

In the past I've always check to see if myDuck is null

```
if (myDuck == null)
{
  // Do stuff
}
```

I've recently looked at some code that check for null first.

```
if (null == myDuck)
{
   // Do stuff
}
```

It seems to me that these are the same, but are there any differences between these two?  Is there any performance benefits to one over the other?  Is there a recommended best practice for checking if an object is null?

Comment: Dupie McDuperson: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/655657/0-variable-or-null-obj-an-outdated-practice-in-c/655670#655670

Comment: Dupes of at least 3: http://askjonskeet.com/search/?q=typo+C%2B%2B

Comment: I tried to do my due diligence, searching for a dup on this.  To me it was a very hard concept to verbalize in a concise fashion.  Either way, thanks for the great responses.

Comment: @bendewey: Absolutely, various questions are tricky to find, including this one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The second stems from C/C++ (and elsewhere) where this is a valid construct

```
if (myDuck = null) {
}
```

That's not valid in C# (unless your expression resolves to a boolean). For example, this is valid C#

```
bool b = ...
if (b = true) {
}
```

Putting the constant first was defensive to stop accidental assignment when you wanted comparison.  I'd say more people put the variable to the left but there is nothing wrong with putting the constant to the left either.

Just pick one and be consistent about it.

Comment: yes, where "if (myDuck = null)" is a valid construct AND it can cause BIG, hard to find, program errors.

Comment: I've never seen that error in my code, maybe it was a big thing in the 80s

Comment: Most compilers throw a warning on the assignment-in-conditional usage these days. But if you've ever blown a whole day overlooking the obvious you get gun shy about it.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference occurs if you were to put this by accident:

```
if(myDuck = null) ...
```

But in reality, the C# compiler is smart enough to detect this.

If you put this by accident:

```
if(null = myDuck) ...
```

Then this would result in an error back in the C or C++ days.

Long story short: it makes no difference in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Putting 'null' first prevents accidental assignment  if (myDuck=null).  However, some compilers throw an error when trying to do that, and therefore the point is moot.  IMO it all comes down to style - pick one, and stick with it :)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no difference whatsoever.

The if-statement will simply check wheter or not the expression it contains is true. Wheter myDuck is to the left of the right of the == symbol makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

One looks like C++ syntax, the other like Java or C#.

From what I've read, The "null == myDuck" syntax originated in C from people accidently assigning in their if statements:

```
if (myDuck = null)
  // returns true
```