# PHP: order of operators in a comparison null

Tags: php, operators

I usually write this:

```
if ($myvar == null)
```

but sometimes I read this:

```
if (null == $myvar)
```

I remember somebody told me the latter is better but I don't remember why.

Do you know which is better and why?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271561/why-does-one-often-see-null-variable-instead-of-variable-null-in-c and many others

Answer (score 11):

If you accidentally forget one of the `=`, the second one will give an error.

```
if ($myvar = null)
```

This will assign `null` to `$myvar` and perform the `if` check on the result.

```
if (null = $myvar)
```

This will try to assign the value of `$myvar` to `null` and give an error because you cannot assign to `null`.

Answer (score 1):

It is not about the order, it is about avoiding accidental skipping one `=`, which will result in assignment instead of comparison. When using constant-first convention, accidental skipping will throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

What this person may have alluded to was micro optimizations regarding conditional statements. For example, in the following, the second condition would not be evaluated as the first already failed.

```
if (1 == 0 && 1 == 1)
```

However, what you have will always be evaluated. Therefore order doesn't matter, and the convention mentioned already is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the latter used to help avoid programmer errors such as:

```
if($myvar = null)
```

this will always return true, whereas

```
if(null = $myvar)
```

will throw an error.

Comment: No, the first one will return `null`, which evaluates to `false` in the boolean conversion, so this conditional will never pass.  The other problem is that it will also set `$myvar` to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `is_null()` instead.

Comment: Not what he was asking, this is about operand order.

Answer (score 0):

Using the assignment operator `=` in place of the equality operator `==` is a common mistake:

```
if($myvar = null)
```

which actually assigns `null` to `$myvar`. One way to get this logical error caught is to use the constant on the LHS so that if you use `=` in place of `==` you'll get an error as constants (`null` in this case) cannot be assigned values: