# Difference between Forward and Reverse Comparison in C#

Tags: c#, comparison

this is related to comparing values in C#.

basically by default, in C# till date i only used forward comparison as follows:

```
string value1 = "";

if (value1 == null) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("True"); 
} 
else 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("False"); 
}
```

somewhere on Internet, i came across a link where it is said that while comparing values in C#, we should prefer Reverse Comparison as :

```
string value1 = "";

if (null == value1)  
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("True"); 
} 
else 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("False"); 
}
```

Now the problem is that is there any basic difference between the two ways of comparing values or not (i.e. both are same).

Looking for favorable replies.

Thanks

Comment: personally, (null == value1) read to hard very is.

Comment: @JTA: some people just follow the "best practices" even though they don't get why ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does one often see "null != variable" instead of "variable != null" in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271561/why-does-one-often-see-null-variable-instead-of-variable-null-in-c)

Comment: As, we use `int i=1; j=2;....` so its easy to follow same pattern `if(i==1)`

Answer (score 4):

This is a hangover from languages where values are implicitly converted to a boolean type.

For the most part, anything that was non-`null` or non-`0` would be treated as `true`, otherwise it was equivalent to `false`. This meant that any assignation of a constant would always be `true`.

This thing to remember here is that **the assignment function returns the value assigned**, much in the same way that `5` is the result of `2+3`, `myInt = 5` also returns `5`.

Because of this, it was recommended that you check the variable *against* the constant. The `null` example is actually probably a bit contrived in this case, as it would, in most languages, return as false.

As an example:

```
if(i = 1)
{
    printf("Always out\n");
}
else
{
    printf("Never prints\n");
}
```

`i` is assigned the value of `1`, which then returns the value of the assignment, `1`, to the `if` statement. This is equivalent to `true`, and the `if` condition matches.

If you were to attempt to assign `i` to the constant `1`, you wouldn't compile, and so it was recommended that you do things it that order (e.g. `1 == i`).

This is not neccesary in C#, and further to your example, the recommended practice is to call `if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(myStringValue)) { //.... }`, as a string has... two ... default values from a semantic perspective.

Comment: C# lets you assign inside an if condition (`if((i = 1) == 1)` is useless, but compiles).  However, only bools can be used directly *as* conditions, so in C# this mistake only occurs (rarely) for bools.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen - you are quite correct. The behaviour occurs because the return value of assignment is the actual value itself. I'll update my answer to make that clearer :).

Comment: actually i have raised this question simply to know that whether this reverse comparison or forward comparison has any relation with performance or efficiency or not, that's it. it is also true that reverse comparisons are hard to read.

Comment: @Everest - no, there is no perf benefit AFAIK, and I don't see how there could be. Even if it were more efficient to do comparisons that way, I'm sure the compiler would just switch the order around automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse comparison protects you from errors, when you use `==` (compare) instead of `=` (assign). But complier also warns you if you do this.

Comment: for c# it is true only for booleans, imho.

Comment: You are absoultely right, but sometimes it happens: `while (someWorker.Status = true){ //... }` ))

Comment: case in point for `while(boolVar) { //... }` vs. `while(boolVar == true) { //... }` being the path of righteousness.

Comment: The compile doesn't warn you, it fails to compile with an error if there's no implicit cast to bool.