# if(null!=variable) why not if(variable!=null)

Tags: java, coding-style

Hi
In our company they follow a strict rule of comparing with null values. When I code 
  **if(variable!=null)** in code review I get comments on this to change it to **if(null!=variable)**. Is there any performance hit for the above code?
If anybody explains highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Shouldn't be any performance gain or degradation either way afaik, guess it's just how they like to do it.

Comment: There is a great answer to this question over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271561/why-does-one-often-see-null-variable-instead-of-variable-null-in-c

Comment: This coding style is called "Yoda conditions", if you search for it you find many examples and discussions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271561/why-does-one-often-see-null-variable-instead-of-variable-null-in-c

Comment: @J Angwenyi: The answers there will answer this question, but it's still a different language.

Answer (score 11):

I don't see any advantage in following this convention. In C, where boolean types don't exist, it's useful to write

```
if (5 == variable)
```

rather than

```
if (variable == 5)
```

because if you forget one of the eaqual sign, you end up with

```
if (variable = 5)
```

which assigns 5 to variable and always evaluate to true. But in Java, a boolean is a boolean. And with !=, there is no reason at all.

One good advice, though, is to write

```
if (CONSTANT.equals(myString))
```

rather than

```
if (myString.equals(CONSTANT))
```

because it helps avoiding NullPointerExceptions.

My advice would be to ask for a justification of the rule. If there's none, why follow it? It doesn't help readability.

Comment: If `myString` shouldn't be `null` (which generally it shouldn't), then it's much better to throw an exception than carry on (usually).

Comment: I agree, there's no place for it in Java. It just makes the code harder to read.

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with performance. It's used to prevent that you assign accidentally instead of comparing. An assignment `null = var` won't make any sense. But in Java `var = null` also won't compile so the rule of turning them around doesn't make sense anymore and only makes the code less readable.

Comment: but "if (var = null)" won't compile either.

Comment: @JB Nizet You are right. I thought in C++, will update the answer

Answer (score 3):

No performance difference - the reason is that if you get used to writing `(null == somevar)` instead of `(somevar == null)`, then you'll never accidentally use a single equals sign instead of two, because the compiler won't allow it, where it will allow `(somevar = null)`.  They're just extending this to `!=` to keep it consistent.

I personally prefer `(somevar == null)` myself, but I see where they're coming from.

Comment: I don't see how `somevar = null` will compile in an `if` condition (except if the type of `somevar` is `Boolean`)

Comment: Good point - I don't know about Java, but I know in some of the similarly-structured languages like C or C++, it will compile, with unexpected results. And coding standards tend to carry over to similar languages for a lot of developers.

Answer (score 3):

It's a "left-over" from old C-coding standards.

the expression `if (var = null)` would compile without problems. But it would actually assign the value null to the variable thus doing something completely different. This was the source for very annoying bugs in C programs.

In Java that expression does not compile and thus it's more a tradition than anything else. It doesn't erver any purpose (other than coding style preferences)

Comment: Auto-unboxing. Probably a mistake IMO. `null`s don't help things.