# benefit of using the expression like this rather than using normal expression

Tags: php, c++, c

what is the difference between these two expressions ,

```
if(false == $flag)

if($flag == false)
```

what is the benefit of this expression rather than normal initiation like this :

```
if($flag == false)
```

Comment: Using `if(false == $flag)`, you can prevent accidental assignments inside the `if` statement, but I think it's a matter of preference.

Comment: Everyone I know would write that as `if(!flag)`

Comment: @Ultimater Why, you don't write `if (($a>$b) == true)`?

Comment: You would. `($a>$b)` is also boolean, so by the same logic it should be `if(($a > $b) == true)` ;)

Comment: Okay, found the duplicate. Here you go: [Coding Style - if ('constant' == $variable) vs. if ($variable == 'constant')](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/74086)

Comment: in addition to the other answers

for a detailed discussion (not particularly for php) , see here :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271561/why-does-one-often-see-null-variable-instead-of-variable-null-in-c

Answer (score 3):

In first case, `if(false == $flag)`, compiler warn you if you type accidentally `=` instead of `==`. But this is not true in the second case, `if($flag == false)`.
In second case if `==` is accidentally replaced by `=` then compiler do not show you any warning or error instead `$flag = false` will assign `false` to `flag` and the condition `$flag = false` will always be `false`.