# Regex to find a method with specific return and behviour inside of it

Tags: regex, intellij-idea, structural-search

I want something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26890991/), but within the scope of a method.

Given a project, I want to find all the files with a method which return an specific Object and use another specific method.

Currently I only have this: `MyObject(.)*\((.)*\)[\w\W]*?return` which selects the method with the return I expect, but how can I specify a behaviour inside of it?

Feel free to use another simpler pattern, I don't know if the one I've created is good enough.

And please, explain the Regex as I am not an expert of it, and for future purposes also.

Comment: I would suggest using [Structural Search](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/structural-search-and-replace-examples.html)

Comment: I'm not sure if regex is the right tool for this job.  What's your endgame for this?

Comment: Actually I never used Structural Search on IntelliJ, I will give it a try. But so far seems just another reason for me to love the IDE.

Comment: @JNYRanger Yeah I agree with you, but that was the first thing that cross my mind. I have a huge project, and we notice an unnecessary use of an Object. But the object have a quite common use, what I asked would filter almost perfectly the situation where it is really unnecessary. I mean from more de 3k files to something around 50.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly what you want, but you could perform a search with the scope *Files in Previous Search Result*.

Structural Search seems like a better solution to your problem. Use the existing template *methods of the class* and edit the variable **ReturnType** to equal the type you want. Then use the template *method calls* and edit the variable **MethodCall** and search in scope *Previous Search Results*.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting a better solution (the same go to @Meo). As I said before, just one more reason to love IntelliJ :)