# PHP if statement null === $variable: what for?

Tags: php

Often, I see in if statements for php something like this:

```
if (null === $variable) {
    // do stuff
}
```

What does it do and what is it for?

EDIT: I totally get that it is a comparison operator, I just wonder why not `$variable === null`.

Comment: Those aren't assignments, they are checks to see if a variable is null or not

Comment: Please find out in the documentation the difference between `=`, `==` and `===`

Comment: @AndrewL., sorry my mistake corrected, but why not to check like this `$variable === null`? why it's the other way around?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions

Comment: determines whether equal value are identical and of the same type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not an *assignment*, it's a *comparison* for equality. It determines if the variable `$variable` contains the value `null`.

More in the documentation:

- [Assignment Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php)
- [Comparison Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

> why not to check `$variable === null`

Some people like to use the form with the constant on the left (a "Yoda condition", it is called) so that if they have a typo and only type a single `=`, it causes a syntax error rather than doing an assignment.

Comment: sorry modified the question, but why not to check `$variable === null`?

Comment: Not the same language, but same reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271561/why-does-one-often-see-null-variable-instead-of-variable-null-in-c

Comment: @DimaDz: I've added a note above about that.

Answer (score 1):

That is the Yoda style usually used as a trick by programmers to prevent accidental assignments which always  give some silent bugs.

Example:

```
  var a = dosomething();

  if(a = null){
      //more here
   }
```

Note that the if block will always not execute regardless of the result of `doSomething` method since we assign then check for equality. This assignment nullifies the possibly non-deterministic nature of `doSomething`